# having trouble convert getJSON data to model

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I can't seem to get Knockout to work when having collections that are recieved from getJSON.  Here is an example of my code

```
function MyTestModel() {
     this.modelProperty = ko.observable();
     this.myCompute = ko.computed(function () {
          return "test";
});
}

function MyViewModel() {
     var self = this;
     self.myTestModels = ko.observableArray();
}

var vm = new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("http://MyUrl.com/api/MyController", function (data) {
    var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    var array = observableData();
    vm.myTestModels(array);
     });
  });

 <tbody data-bind="foreach: myTestModels">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: modelProperty" ></td>
        <td data-bind="text: myCompute" ></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>

 [{"modelProperty":"My Property 1"},{"modelProperty":"My Property 2"}]
```

What happens is the data for modelProperty shows but Chrome JavaScript console says:
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: myCompute is not defined;
Bindings value: text: myCompute

It appears ko.mapping.fromJS is not converting it to MyTestModel.  I'm thinking this is because knockout doesn't know about MyTestModel but I'm not sure how to tell is about my model?

Anyway, thanks for everyone's time!

Comment: Can you show the chargeEliminations function and the json which is in data ?

Comment: chargeEliminations should have been myTestModels.  I changed the name of everything for the example.

Comment: Also added json data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did't specify that the array items should be convert into MyTestModel.

This converts each array item into MyTestModel:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://MyUrl.com/api/MyController", function (data) {
        var array = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
            return new MyTestModel(item.modelProperty);
        });
        vm.myTestModels(array);
    });
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s698a/)

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, that worked!  Just wondering, is there a way to auto map it and not pass the properties into the model?

Comment: Yes, you could create a MyTestModel and then set its modelProperty property. But I prefer the first solution.

Comment: Yep, I prefer the first one too.  Thanks!